# Calling a fuction from a .cs file in a .dll

Tags: c#

I seem to be running into a problem while coding.  I am writing a DLL for C#.  In my DLL I need to place some code in a function.  The problem that I run into is that the code I need to place in the function is written in the program that is using the DLL.  For example:

#### MyDLL.dll

```
using OtherGuyDLL.dll

public void Function1()
{
    OtherGuyEventHandler += DLLFunction;
}

private void DLLFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProgramFunction();
}
```

#### Program.cs

```
using MyDLL.dll

public void ProgramFunction()
{
    //My code
}
```

The problem occurs when `MyDLL.dll` is compiled.  You get an error since `ProgramFunction()` does not exist due to the DLL not being used by `Program.cs` at the time.  Is there anyway around this?

**EDIT:** To further explain, `DLLFunction()` is actually called by an event handler. I'm using a 3rd party DLL in my DLL.  I want the user of my DLL to be able to specify some code which will in turn be used during an event.  The purpose of my DLL is mainly for ease of use.  I've updated my example code to better picture this.

Comment: That does not look like a DLL, did you add the reference to the project in the solution ?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about the flow of execution here? There are a few ways of doing this. It sounds like you want your program to register a callback or event with the DLL class. Or you can subclass the DLL class in your program..

Comment: Well, here's an example using an event: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gzX9pq

Comment: @t0mm13b This is just example code I've written to illustrate my problem not the actual DLL I'm writing.

Comment: @Blorgbeard hopefully my edit helps

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm not a huge fan of the `sender/eventArgs` delegate, I'll go with that since it's already in use.

The external library can't have internal knowledge of your application (including the methods of your `Program` class) because that would be a circular reference. Each would require the other to compile before it could compile.

What you can do is in your `EventArgs` pass a reference to the function that you want the external .dll to call.

In this example the `MyEventArgs` class contains a reference to an `Action`. When you call `ExecuteCallback` that `Action` is invoked. You could also make that `Action` a public property and then the event handler could just call it directly.

You would declare `MyEventArgs` in the external library.

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly Action _callback { get; set;}

    public MyEventArgs(Action callback = null)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public void ExecuteCallback()
    {
        _callback?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Now the class that raises the event would do

```
new MyEventArgs(this.ProgramFunction)
```

(assuming that the class raising the event is the same one that contains `ProgramFunction`.

I don't know the specifics, but that's the general pattern. Instead of the referenced library knowing which method to call, the calling library passes the function to it.

Comment: ProgramFunction() is in MyProgram.cs.  The event handler "OtherGuyEventHandler" is specified in the 3rd party DLL OtherGuyDLL.dll.  The DLL I'm making, "MyDLL.dll", calls the event handler in a function, Function1().  The event has to execute code that is specified in MyProgram.cs.  However, the event is from OtherGuyDLL.dll, and is utilized in MyDLL.dll.  And also the code the event needs to execute, ProgramFunction() is defined in MyProgram.cs.  Hopefully this helps to explain the specifics of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you raise the event and then call `ProgramFunction()` yourself, or does OtherGuyDLL.dll have to call it? If they define the event then the only way to call something back is if the event they defined includes a callback.

Comment: Yes I can.  The event handler is just a part of OtherGuyDLL.dll.